# Finding EditText Editable getSpans Start and End Index

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, spannablestring

I am trying to get All Spans applied to text as below;

```
public String getTextWithTags(Editable e)
{

    StyleSpan[] ss = e.getSpans(0,e.length(),StyleSpan.class);
    ss[0].getSpanStart <--- ? This is the problem, no such function

    return "";
}
```

But there is no index find function to replace tags to store them on database so i can retrieve all spans back when i reopen text. How can i get all span positions from editable object?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
StyleSpan[] ss = e.getSpans(0,e.length(),StyleSpan.class);

for(StyleSpan span : ss){
    int start = e.getSpanStart(span);
    int end = e.getSpanEnd(span);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! how did i miss this ? Tiring day i guess.. have a nice day. I can't accept this as accepted answer for 5 minutes, but after than i will do it. Also ss[0].getStyle() == Typeface.BOLD can i get the style type like this?

Comment: Yes you can do it that way

Answer (score 1):

If u want to find Span start/end index, you can use this(example for a single `RelativeSizeSpan`) -

```
val sb = text as SpannableStringBuilder
val firstSpan = getSpans(0, length, RelativeSizeSpan::class.java).first()
val start = (sb as Spanned).getSpanStart(firstSpan)
val end = (sb as Spanned).getSpanEnd(firstSpan)
```

Comment: It should be getSpanStart instead of the first getSpanEnd :-)